# Why pandas does not work when using xlwings in RunPython macro

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xlwings

I don't know why but I keep having this error when I use pandas and xlwings:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\marchandbo\desktop\anacredit\4.projets\projets\anacredit\python\1_anacredit_tool\Start_production.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\marchandbo\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

I tried all the solutions I could find (uninstall pandas, numpy, then reinstall)... but nothing worked. Would this be an issue with python 3.7 ?

Comment: You might be seeing this issue: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/954

Comment: Hi there :) please include all text info (e.g. error messages) as *text* directly in your question, not in linked text or linked images

Comment: @FelixZumstein, I believe this is it. There are some kind of bugs with the 3.7 version. It actually worked the whole day yesterday until 6pm, and then crashed again. I'll try using an anterior version of pyhon

Comment: Python 3.7 works fine as long as you use the latest version of pywin32 also (224). The issue I am referring to is with NumPy installed via conda.

Comment: thank you. I found out that i'm using the 223. So the next course of action would be to uninstall numpy via _conda uninstall numpy_ and then reinstall using pip ?